# Is it possible to reuse or the oil recovered from a spill?

Tags: soil

I don´t know if this is the rifght place to ask this question, but I would like to know if after the remediation of a soil contaminated with hydrocarbon you can reuse or even sell the oil recovered. And if it's possible, do you know any companie that can do that?

Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean petroleum; crude and products are collected as much as possible , and taken to the refinery for processing. In much of the world , what can not be collected is burned in situ, this was formerly done in the US also. Today, in the US , regulations create a problem and contaminated soil is dug up and hauled someplace for cleaning . The burned soil is sterile but recovers - builds up organic matter- in a year +/-. Of course there are many degrees of variation. For example , I understand there pools of oil laying on the ground in Russia where the logistics of moving equipment into the site are difficult/expensive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. With "what can not be collected is burned in situ" you mean that some oil can be reused, right?

Comment: They suck up all they can ; a little sand and water is no problem because that contamination is the same as in crude.